# Error in debug.log

Tags: magento2.3, debug

I found below errors in `debug.log` file.

```
[2020-07-09 00:59:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'msp-recaptcha-newsletter-popup' element cannot be added as child to 'footer2', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the '7d064a79356a393a42e8c51c47c9f49f' element cannot be added as child to 'left.menu', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'footer.custom.block' tries to reorder itself towards 'copyright', but their parents are different: 'footer.content.bottom' and 'footer' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'authorization-link-login' tries to reorder itself towards 'register-link', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'top.links' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'msp-recaptcha-newsletter-popup' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'footer2' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'store_language' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_switcher', but their parents are different: 'header.panel.right' and 'header.panel.store' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'msp-recaptcha-newsletter-popup' element cannot be added as child to 'footer2', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the '7d064a79356a393a42e8c51c47c9f49f' element cannot be added as child to 'left.menu', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.top.slideshow' element cannot be added as child to 'page.top.custom', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'footer.custom.block' tries to reorder itself towards 'copyright', but their parents are different: 'footer.content.bottom' and 'footer' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'authorization-link-login' tries to reorder itself towards 'register-link', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'top.links' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'msp-recaptcha-newsletter-popup' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'footer2' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.top.slideshow' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'page.top.custom' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-07-09 00:59:58] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'store_language' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_switcher', but their parents are different: 'header.panel.right' and 'header.panel.store' respectively. [] []
```

What is the solution of these errors ?